# Chroot on macOS 11 Big Sur fails with dyld: Library not loaded error

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, big-sur

I've looked up plenty of guides and helper scripts on GitHub on how to set up a chroot jail on macOS ([Mac-Hroot](https://github.com/jsarenik/Mac-Hroot), [macos-mkjail](https://github.com/tabulon-ext/macos-mkjail), [mkjail](https://github.com/skissane/mkjail), [jailkit](https://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/index.html#download), [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356970/how-do-i-create-a-minimal-chroot-jail-in-macos)) yet none of the tested solutions work.

In theory, a chroot jail is simple to set up on Linux by just copying a binary like `bash` and all its dependencies into the new root folder. On macOS, however, the dyld shared cache causes problems because it fails to load libraries that do not exist in the filesystem but only in the dyld shared cache. It appears something changed with dyld in one of the recent macOS releases, because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262649/osx-and-chroot-unable-to-find-bin-bash) solution no longer works.

I am setting up a chroot jail as follows:

```
cp -r /bin ./
mkdir usr
cp -r /usr/lib ./usr
sudo chroot ./ /bin/bash
```

Result:

```
dyld: dyld cache load error: shared cache file open() failed
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /bin/bash
  Reason: image not found
[1]    12345 abort      sudo chroot ./ /bin/bash
```

Again, according to [this old-ish answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262649/osx-and-chroot-unable-to-find-bin-bash) having the file `/usr/lib/dyld` in the chroot jail should be sufficient to work around this issue, but that's not the case here. I did copy the `/usr/lib/dyld` file over to the chroot.

What I also tried is copying the contents of `/System/Library/dyld/` to the chroot jail. This is the location of the dyld shared cache on Big Sur. After doing so the `chroot` command hangs for a long time until failing again with a different error:

```
dyld: dyld cache load error: syscall to map cache into shared region failed
```

Has anybody managed to get chroot jails working on Big Sur or has any insights on this?

Comment: This is a dupe of [How do I create a minimal chroot jail in macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356970/how-do-i-create-a-minimal-chroot-jail-in-macos). TL;DR: Apple broke `chroot`ing since macOS 11.0.1 :(